# TypeScript Promise TS2304 TS2529

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I had the following code:

```
function asyncFunc1(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>(x => x);
}
```

which produced the following error:

> TS2304: cannot find name 'Promise'

So I changed it to explicitly declare 'Promise':

```
///<reference path="../typings/modules/bluebird/index.d.ts" />

import * as Promise from 'bluebird';

function asyncFunc1(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>(x => x);
}
```

and now I get the following error:

> TS2529: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'. Compiler reserves name
>   'Promise' in top level scope of a module containing async functions

How can I solve this paradox?

Comment: what's your compilerOptions.target in your tsconfig?

Comment: @Paarth I'm targeting to es5

Comment: Do you have any other modules installed that define Promise, such as core-js or es6-promise?

Comment: The error suggests that Promise is being reserved by TypeScript. Have you tried importing like: `import * as Bluebird from 'bluebird';` and using it as `function asyncFunc1(): Bluebird<string>`?

Comment: what line is TS2529 coming from? have you tried calling the bluebird import "bluebird" or something besides Promise? This could be a symptom of typescript 2.0+ requiring all async functions to use the global Promise, therefore reserving it for itself.

Comment: @nbering I don't really need Blubird. I've added it to get rid of the first error: TS2304: cannot find name 'Promise'. Please read my question again carefully.

Comment: @Catalyst I don't really need Blubird. I've added it to get rid of the first error: TS2304: cannot find name 'Promise'. Please read my question again carefully.

Comment: @DaveV by a chance I added a reference to 'mongodb'  module which contains a declaration for 'Promise'. It eliminated the TS2304 so I could remove the "import * as Promise from 'bluebird'", but hovering 'Promise' doesn't recognize it and suggests me to click "alt + enter" which adds to my code 'import {Promise} from "~mongodb~es6-promise";' which produces again the TS2529 error, so I guess it would be the same with either core-js or es6-promise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Promises are only available in ES6

If you set the target to ES6, the typescript compiler uses a different base library to for basic type checking against types included in the language specification. Make sure you are targeting ES6.

## Promises in TypeScript without Targeting ES6

If you want access to definition of Constructors as methods defined in the es2015 specification, that have been implemented by browsers and NodeJS (via V8 engine) before language features - like arrow functions, destructuring, etc - you can do that.

What you want to do is configure TypeScript to target es5, not include and default library, and reference the default library yourself.

Your tsconfig might look something like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions: {
    "noLib": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    }
   "files": [
     "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts",
     "app.ts",
   ]
}
```

The above examples assumes that typescript is installed directly in your project. If it is not you can always copy from your typescript installation's folder and include it in your project.

This solution should give you typings for the Promise constructor, as well as a variety of other features like array.includes() and a few other things. This comes with the downside that you won't get type errors for things that are not implemented in the browsers, but if you're using Promise anyway you're probably targeting modern-browsers only, or you're using Node where you control the runtime environment.

Comment: Thanks for keeping helping me. I didn't get notified for your comments to your previous answer because you hadn't tagged me (@Alon). I would have tell you that I must target my project to ES6. Hope you will find another solution that will fit my constrains :-)

Comment: @Alon Wait, so you're targeting ES6 and you don't have Promise available already? Are you already using the --no-lib compiler option?

Comment: OK I figured it out. When I posted this question I was transpiling to ES5. Then for another reason I moved to ES6, and I didn't have the TS2304 already but the TS2529 one because I'd added the "import from Bluebird" so I didn't notice it had solved my bug. Now after you'd asked it explicitly checked it and realized that moving to ES6 has solved this bug too.

Comment: Edit: I added a note to the answer to check language target.

Answer (score 1):

It seems TypeScript is protecting the Promise identifier. Try importing as a name other than Promise, or use a different set of typings. There are a few suggestions in this TypeScript GitHub issue.

[Async / await with Bluebird promises](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8331)

The issue is regarding the use of a different promise library with Async Await, but this very situation is likely why they are protecting the Promise name. Specifically, when we use Async/Await in TypeScript the compiler converts this to a Promise in the emitted code, so the compiler is trying to protect the Promise constructor from being over-written. You can always trick the compiler with this sort of thing, but be sure to ask yourself if it's the right thing to do.

Comment: I don't really need Blubird. I've added it to get rid of the first error: TS2304: cannot find name 'Promise'. Please read my question again carefully.

Comment: Then you need to target es6.

Comment: Or you can go somewhere half way and use the es6 library declarations but target the es5 language features.