# How can I use await/async in TypeScript (angular2) when targeting Safari?

Tags: typescript, async-await

I have added some code similar to the following in my project:

```
async fun2(): Promise<string> {
  let token: string = null;

  await this.auth.getToken().then(newToken => {
    token = newToken;
  });

  return token;
}
```

However, when it is compiling, I get the warning:

```
Async functions are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 or higher.
```

When I try to run the project in Chrome it works fine, however in Safari I get an error on `__awaiter` function.

```
proj.prototype.fun2 = function () {
        return __awaiter(this, void 0, Promise, function * () {
            var token = null;
```

What do I need to do to use async/await in Safari with Typescript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `tsconfig.json`, you need to set `"target": "es6"` in the `compilerOptions` section. Note that only Safari v10.0 is fully ES6 compliant, so you need to be on that version. Your code will likely not run in other browsers, as their `ES6/ES2015` support is not yet complete.

Promise is part of ES2015, so nothing needs to be done if you switch to the `es6` target.

**UPDATE**: As of TypeScript 2.1, you can use `async/await` when targeting ES5.

Comment: not working in older (safari 9) browsers is a problem.  I'm going to look into babel.  Thanks.

Comment: You can still use TypeScript with `"target": "es5"` but then you won't be able to use async/await. This is planned for the TypeScript 2.1 release which will be available in November.

Comment: Right.  When I tried es5, I noticed that it stopped working in safari, and I am sure it is also broken in other files.

Answer (score 4):

1) Make sure you have TypeScript 2.1. Earlier versions don't fully support `async await` when targeting ES5.

2) To make `Promise` valid in ES5, follow the instructions of the accepted answer of this question: [TypeScript Promise TS2304 TS2529](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39958914/typescript-promise-ts2304-ts2529/40025904#40025904)